# Show/Hide a form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide and show "form1". But even simply hiding doesn't work.
Where is the mistake?

```
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("F1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    </script>

    <form id="F1" name="form1">
        <p class="style14">blah-blah
            <input type="text" size="1" name="rd"> blah
        </p>
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you need to make sure your `script` tag is at the bottom of the `body` or use the `DOMContentLoaded` event

like so

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   var form = document.getElementById('F1');

   form.style.visibility="hidden"; 
   // OR
   form.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Your `F1` needs to be a string, right now you're referring to a undefined variable.

And I also recommend using `display` instead of `visibility`

@update to comment.

The opposites of them are

```
visibility: visible;
```

AND

```
display: block; // Or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks Connor, it works. What are the opposites to 
visibility="hidden";
display = 'none';
?
To show back the form.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong

```
document.getElementById(thediv).style.visibility="hidden";
```

What is "thediv" you should use :

```
document.getElementById("F1").style.visibility="hidden";
```

Answer (score -1):

F1 should be wrapped in quotes.  You also might need to encompass your code within the `onload` function

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("F1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try `document.getElementById("F1").style.visibility=hidden;`